# Appending 14 Gig of Data to the end of an EXE File

Tags: c++

I created my own single-file installer for my product Wusik Station and it works for the small versions: Demonstration (400 meg) and Engine/Update version (45 meg). But the FULL 14 Gig version does not work, the EXE doesn't run. So I wonder if there are limitations for Windows 10 on such files.

The way I created the file is simple, I just append the data that I want to the end of the EXE and for the last part I add int64(size of the data) so I know how large the data is. Very simple and works, until I do the 14 Gig version. :-(

So, please, if anyone could give me some directions I would be very glad. I can show the actual code, if needed, them I upload to my GitHub area.

Here is one of the files that WORKS:
http://wusik.com/wsv8public/WIN_Wusik_Station_V9_Demonstration_64_Bits.exe

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "This app can’t run on your PC check with software publisher"

That is on launch of WIN_Wusik_Station_V9_Full.exe

Smartscreen is OFF on my machine. Tried to change compatibility Win7 and Win8 without success.

Comment: Google "windows maximum exe size" for basic hits.  First one is good.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976693/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-pe-file-on-64-bit-windows

Comment: Oh, I had this notion that the limitations was only for 32 bits systems. :-o Thanks guys!!! This really sucks... I just wanted a single-file installer. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments it turns out that EXE files can't go above 4 Gig, even on 64 bits systems.