# Add big (> 2GB) resource asset to an executable

Tags: windows, qt, gcc, assets, executable-format

I want to make a simple, minimalist custom cross-platform installer for a specific Qt application. The installer looks like this:

[image: Simple Installer UI]

But in one use-case, the data to store there is > 5GB long. I have tried the following:

1. Using Qt Installer Framework

   - Does not allow offline updates.
   - It is not possible (or it is very hard) to make a custom Qt Quick Controls 2 UI like the shown above
2. Compiling Qt statically and embed the resource with `rcc`

   - Success on compiling Qt statically
   - Using `CONFIG += resources_big` in `.pro` file to allow two-pass of `rcc` tool to compile the big resources
   - Does works for files with < 2GB, but not for larger ones. **I use this for files with < 2GB**
   - If > 2GB, the linker (`ld`) fails with `...relocation truncated to fit...`
   - I added the flag `-mcmodel=medium` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486116/what-does-this-gcc-error-relocation-truncated-to-fit-mean). It does not works, nor does `-mcmodel=large` nor `-Wl,--image-base -Wl,0x100000000` nor `-Wl,--image-base -Wl,0x180000000`
3. Compiling Qt statically and append data to the end of the executable (this seems to be the best approach for > 2GB files)

   - Append my > 5GB zip-compressed test file
   - Append 8 bytes with the size in bytes
   - Works on Linux
   - Works on Windows with no so large files (shows *This app cannot run on your PC*)

I want some advices about how to make the third approach work, as it seems to be the best one for > 2GB files. But new and fresh ideas are welcome too.

An alternative cross-platform installer framework that correct the missing features of Qt's one is also welcome.

I do not want to involve the `winapi` if possible. But a short and easy-to-implement solution will be accepted too.

BTW, I currently have a PC with 4GB of RAM. But this have not been a problem.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6976693/1983398), I don't think it's possible to make any executable >2GB.

Comment: I already saw it. But with installer frameworks you can create an executable with more of 2 GB. In fact, I saw a working FIFA installer with > 20 GB. Also, with WinRAR you can do that too (a self-extracting file).

Comment: I tried to create a WinRAR self-extracting file larger than 4GB, but I failed.
I even got this error message from WinRAR: `Too large SFX archive. Windows cannot run the executable file exceeding 4 GB.`

Comment: Hmmm... I have created self-extracting files before, and one of them more than 2 GB (an installer for a GTA game), but its size was > 2GB (2.6 I think). I have never tried one with more than 4 GB. I will give a try. Also I will make some tests with the Qt Installer Framework to see if it has some limits. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yes, >2GB works for the self-extractor, but not >4GB.
And you really have a >20GB FIFA installer executable?

Comment: Ups sorry for the delay. Yes a also checked that > 2GB works for the self-extractor but no >4GB. The Qt installer frameworks also fails with > 4GB, which is a problem because the installer right now is 3.6 GB (Qt 5.13.2).

Comment: And yes. I used a FIFA installer with more that 20 GB. I do not have it anymore. It installed FIFA and lots of mods/updates. That was back in 2014 I think, and I remember that it tooks a lot of time to load (more than 15 minutes). BTW, sorry my english (it's not my mother lang).